# Wares accessible to all Characters

Tags: divinity-original-sin-2

In Divinity Original Sin 2 (DoS from hereafter), you have the option to mark items as wares. This makes it extremely convenient to sell items to a vendor. Something I have not figured out is how to make those wares accessible between characters when selling to a merchant. There are many forums discussing not being able to know how, but none have been answered.

I have 1 character that puts points into bartering for RP purposes that is not my main character so it is pretty cumbersome to individually grab every item to place in my companion's inventory.

Is there a way to make it so any characters can access the wares on the vendor screen in DoS? If no, is there a method to make a quick transfer from one inventory to another?

Answer (score 3):

put them in a separate bag when marking them,
move bag between persons